# Echo number of tabs based on variable

Tags: php

I am trying to create the bottom two triangles but I can't get the alignment to work properly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZgse.jpg

I can't figure out how to do the spacing properly. In Python you could do ('A' * 200) and it would print the A 200 times, however I can't figure out how to do that with the \t tab in PHP. Is it possible to do something like that so I can space out the number triangle based on tabs?

Comment: spaces in a `<pre>` tag would work better, show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function like so:

```
echo str_repeat('Z', 4); // ZZZZ
```